# Unable to change the gridview column width programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, .net-2.0

On my windows form, I need to programatically set the width of columns in the grid view. I am using the following code:

```
this.dgridv.Columns[columnName].Width = columnWidth;
```

The above stmt runs without any error. But, the column width remains unchanged. If I insert a breakpoint and check the value of width after the stmt runs, it is still 100, which I guess is the default value of datagrid column width.

Is there something else I need to do apart from this? Are there any values I need to set before changing the column width?

Any help or pointers on this are highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
this.dgridv.Columns[columnName].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
this.dgridv.Columns[columnName].Width = columnWidth;
```

To reset it back, I am using:

```
dgvCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you got the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` set to Fill?

If you have you'll need to set the `FillWeight` property instead. This isn't a simple width but the proportion of `width / no. columns` that this column takes up.

If you haven't resized the columns it will be 100.0.

If the column has been widened it will be > 100.0.

If the column has been shrunk it will be < 100.0.

Widening one column, by definition, shrinks the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`dataGridView1.Columns[index].Width = 150;`

This line of code will set the column width programatically.